# $aRb$ iff $a+3b$ is multiple of $4$

Tags: equivalence-relations, binary

I'm stuck with the following exercice I need to prove that this is an equivalence relation, and also calculcate it's equivalence classes

So far I know it has to be reflexive, symmetric and transitive:

Reflexive:

$$a + 3b = 4a$$

So it is reflexive

Now I'm stuck proving symmetric and transitive, and it's equivalence classes.

Any help please?

Comment: Try symm: if $a +3b=4k$ for some $k$, is it true that $b+3a=4l$ for some $l$ ?

Comment: From the first one we have: $a=4k-3b$. Then subst in the second one...

Answer (score 0):

For symmetric, if $a+3b$ is a multiple of $4$, you want to show that $3a+b$ is a multiple of $4$ too. 
If 
$$a+3b = 4k$$
$$3a+b=(3a+9b)-8b$$

Guide for transitive:

$$a+3b = 4k$$
$$b+3c = 4l$$

Express $a+3c$ in terms of $k$ and $b$ and see what do you get.

Remark: there is a small typo in your proof of reflexive.

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive:
$$a+3a=4a$$

Symmetric:
$$a+3b=4k \implies b+3a = b+3(4k-3b) = \dots$$

Transitive:
$$
\left.\begin{array}{r}
a+3b=4k_1\\
b+3c=4k_2
\end{array}\right\} \implies a+3c = (4k_1-3b) + (4k_2-b) = \dots$$

Regarding the equivalence class, assuming you are working in $\mathbb{Z}$, note that
$$ a+3b = 4k \Leftrightarrow a-b = a+3b-4b = 4l. $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  $a + 3 b \equiv a - b \bmod{4}$